# Hindi not supported? - iTunes Connect (App Store)

Tags: applications, ios-appstore, app-store-connect, internationalization, language

Trying to create a new app and while Chinese, Russian, Japanese, Arabic and Korean was created without any issue, Hindi gives an error:

> App Name must not contain the following characters: जी वं त ...

Any idea? Hindi isn't supported?

Answer (score 1):

[Apple's list of supported languages](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/AppStoreTerritories.html) for the App Store does **not** include Hindi.

It does include language support for:

> - Chinese (Simplified)
> - Chinese (Traditional)
> - Danish
> - Dutch
> - English (Australia)
> - English (Canada)
> - English (U.K.)
> - English (U.S.)
> - Finnish
> - French
> - French (Canada)
> - German
> - Greek
> - Indonesian
> - Italian
> - Japanese
> - Korean
> - Malay
> - Norwegian
> - Portuguese (Brazil)
> - Portuguese (Portugal)
> - Russian
> - Spanish (Mexico)
> - Spanish (Spain)
> - Swedish
> - Thai
> - Turkish
> - Vietnamese

Comment: this one is not quiet what I'm looking for as these are the App Store localizations (the App Store is available in these languages) but in fact more languages are supported such as Hebrew, Arabic, etc. and that's the list (more the reason why Hindi was left out) we're asking for

Comment: The link I posted indicated "The list below shows the supported languages available on iTunes Connect for your App Store metadata. The languages in which you choose to localize your metadata will be displayed to customers according to their storefront and device settings.". I'm reading that to indicate Hindi isn't supported for the app metadata. That's not what you were looking for?

Comment: Here is an example of an Arabic localization [App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/albth-almbashr/) and as you see, Arabic is not in the list you mentioned yet the app is using Arabic script.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=12132018a

Hindi is supported:
https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev656087953

> - Catalan
> - Chinese (Simplified)
> - Chinese (Traditional)
> - Croatian
> - Czech
> - Danish
> - Dutch
> - English (Australia)
> - English (Canada)
> - English (U.K.)
> - English (U.S.)
> - Finnish
> - French
> - French (Canada)
> - German
> - Greek
> - Hindi
> - Hungarian
> - Indonesian
> - Italian
> - Japanese
> - Korean
> - Malay
> - Norwegian
> - Polish
> - Portuguese (Brazil)
> - Portuguese (Portugal)
> - Romanian
> - Russian
> - Slovak
> - Spanish (Mexico)
> - Spanish (Spain)
> - Swedish
> - Thai
> - Turkish
> - Ukrainian
> - Vietnamese